# Is it possible to purchase music on an iPhone without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

Do any music stores beyond iTunes exist that allow you to legally purchase content *on* an iPhone? That is to say, is it possible to purchase music without connecting to a computer? Streaming or downloading are both ok.  Through an app or a website is also ok.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the service, it seems that Rhapsody does more or less what you are asking for -- a music store on the iPhone that is separate from iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I have used MOG on an iPod touch to download music from their library to my iPod Touch for offline listening.  As I understand the contract, I do not own the content, only the right to listen to it during my contract term.

Comment: This and rhapsody both sound interesting, I'll check them out.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Why the downvote? Something wrong with MOG?